# Do employers look at the resume or the site profile when you apply through Careers?

Tags: discussion, support, jobs

When you apply to a job on careers does your careers profile automatically get linked to your application, and if so do you think that the employer looks more at that or at the resume given?

Comment: The whole *point* of using careers is that your profile is linked when applying for jobs.  Otherwise it wouldn't be any different from just [e-]mailing in your resume directly and bypassing SE entirely.

Comment: In careers they send your complete profile .

Comment: Even if you have a lesser profile, the merely act of applying over Careers may be positive, better over other applying channels. Happens.